# How can I duplicate content

Tags: ee2, duplicate

I have two channels product & product_info.
The product and product_info have a one to many relationship using playa. The product_info list the product as a parent. Both channels use Matrix fields in the field set.

As a one off event, I need to duplicate a product and all of it's linked product_info entries for versioning purposes. I would like any suggestions on the best way of achieving this.

My current ideas are:
- Dump out the db into a sql file and manually hunt down all the insert statements i want to duplicate and copy/pasta them after doing some find replace on id's
- Write a script to query certain tables and insert them back in as new records
- try and use something like Datagrab

I am currently pushing forward with the db script but I am finding EE database "design" challenging.

thank you for any suggestions

t

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, how about using Cloner? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner

Comment: I have installed mx_cloner and it does the job, however i have several thousand entries to clone and they do need slight title tweaks. So going through each one is time consuming. I have unpicked the db and am nearly there using some python. Whoever decided it was a good idea to keep appending fields as new cols to the exp_channel_data table should be shot.